# AS3 error 1009 root = null

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I don't know much ActionScript. So apologies if this is really simple.

I have written an .as file as part of this I need to be able to stop the flash animation using .stop().

I have tried a few different ways to do this, some of them work - however they always through this error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at com.albionpreview::looptimer/startFrame()    at
>   test_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Here is everything I have tried:

```
this.stop();
root.stop();
MovieClip(root).stop();
MainTimeLine(parent).stop();
MovieClip(parent).stop();
parent.stop();
DisplayObject(stage).stop();
MainTimeline(parent).stop();
Main(root).stop();
Object(root).stop();
this.stage.stop();
MovieClip(this).stop();
MovieClip(this.root).stop();
(root as MovieClip).stop();
```

There must be something simple to try. Anyone can help?

Here is my code if it helps.

http://pastebin.com/HSHCdyr1

Comment: Do you have a bunch of frames on the timeline and you're trying to get the whole thing to stop/pause via timer?

Comment: Yeah, I have an animation on the timeline which is playing. The idea of the script is to time the animation and stop the animation after a given amount of time. For example I may allow the animation to run for 30 seconds. I will time the first loop and see how long it took to animate, from the time of the first loop I can see if I have enough time to loop through again or if I should just stop the animation. I wanted to create some code which I could use in lots of different projects.

Comment: Ok I can help you with the first part. Set a running time and stop when the countdown is finished but I'm not getting your point on second part. Are you saying the animation could be 1 minute long, if it runs for 30 secs you then want code to assess that 30 more secs remain and play again? Are you thinking of keeping a count of frames played against time? I'll pass you some instructions in an Answer then we'll improve via comments...

Comment: Right after spotting that "banner" word, I'm assuming lets say you have an allowed time of 1 minute, you want to be able throw in a 30 sec banner and it runs twice, a 15 sec banner will run four times but a 45 sec will run only once because not enough time to reloop within the 1 minute limit? Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Exactly right. This is for a banner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a new layer I would make a new movieClip that is going to be a container of the frames and control that to stop via timer.

Just draw a box that has a fill colour only (no border). Same width & height as your stage, align to Top & Left (under Modify->Align with "Align to stage" ticked). It should be a perfect fit of stage area now, and then convert it to movieClip (make sure registration is set as a black dot at top/left.. not centered dot).

Call it what you want but give it the instance name of animMC (you can change this later).

Now select the entire range of your animation frames and choose "cut frames" on right-click menu. Double click the animMC movieClip to enter its timeline, delete the box shape and right-click the first frame and "paste frames".

Now in your code you can stop it like this:

```
package com.preview {

import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent     
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class looptimer extends MovieClip
{

var startTime:int = 0;
var allowedTime:int = 5000;
var loopTime:int = 0;


    public function looptimer () 
    {
        var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(5000, 1); //count before doing function "timerListener"  the 1 means do once else it will loop forever
        myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
        myTimer.start();

        function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void
        {
        trace("Timer countdown finished");
        animMC.stop(); //anim stops
        }

    }

}

}
```

========================

## EDIT 2:

Hi this code will check for an event triggered at the end of your anim. To have such event go into the MC that contains the frames and on the last frame (and on blank layer) add this actions code: (This will be the thing that

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("Banner_end)")); //end frame
```

This will be the equivalent of getting your "end Frame". In the code below the event is attached to this instruction:

> animMC.addEventListener("Banner_end", check_Time);

Meaning that on reaching the end frame an event called "Banner end" is despatched from  timeline, this in turn executes the check_Time function and lso another function (see code).

Now this code below will check time and also timer when the "end frame" event was dispatched and work out whether there is enough time for a second loop or more. Two things will affect how times the MC can loop. First is time limit the longer it is the more you loops you'll fit in that limit. Second is length of anim MC which if shorter means can fit more loops in the time limit. Adjust those two things. Easiest is time limit cos you just a change a number ("allowed_playing_Time") for testing but later when you have no control over the limit then you adjust banner (anim MC) frames as needed i.e by adding/dropping  frames.

```
package com.preview 
{
    import flash.utils.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class looptimer extends MovieClip
    {


        var allowed_playing_Time:int = 10; //time limit in seconds
        var play_Count:int = 0; //tracking number of times played
        var can_play_Amount:int = 1; //total times can be played

        var _startTime:Date;//Number;
        var _endTime:Date;//Number;

        //for time check using actual [computer] clock = more accurate than timer
        var real_Time:Date;
        var anim_start_time:int;
        var anim_end_time:int;
        var anim_play_length:int;

        public function looptimer()
        {
            //starting the Banner
            play_Banner_anim();
        }

        function play_Banner_anim():void
        {
            animMC.stop(); //set strating banner state as paused;

            _startTime = real_Time = new Date();//Real Time value initial set here
            trace("current time  at START is: " + _startTime.minutes + " mins past and " + _startTime.seconds + " secs");

            animMC.addEventListener("Banner_end", check_Time);
            animMC.addEventListener("Banner_end", calculate_Replay);
            anim_start_time = getTimer();
            animMC.play();
        }

        function check_Time(e:Event):void
        {
            animMC.stop(); trace( "Banner has reached last frame");
            animMC.removeEventListener("Banner_end", check_Time);
            play_Count = play_Count + 1;
            trace("Times banner has played / looped): " + play_Count);


            _endTime = real_Time = new Date();//new update of Real Time value
            trace("current time at END is: " + _endTime.minutes + " mins past and " + _endTime.seconds + " secs");

            anim_end_time = getTimer();
            anim_end_time = Math.ceil(anim_end_time);
            anim_play_length = Math.round(Math.floor(anim_end_time - anim_start_time) / 1000);

            anim_play_length = anim_play_length;

            trace("checking if Real Time: ");
            var date1:Date = _startTime;
            var date2:Date = _endTime;

            var elapsed1:Number = Date.UTC(date1.minutes,date1.seconds);
            var elapsed2:Number = Date.UTC(date2.minutes,date2.seconds);

            var playingTime:Number = Math.round( (elapsed2/1000) - (elapsed1/1000) );
            trace ("time elasped (delta) is "  +  playingTime );


            //check seconds elapsed in banner playback (i.e total play length)
            trace("Banner total playing length was " + anim_play_length + " seconds");

            //so how many times can banner play within allowed time limit?
            var can_fit_Num:Number = allowed_playing_Time / anim_play_length;

            trace("can fit this many plays in allowed time limit: " + can_fit_Num);
            can_play_Amount = can_fit_Num;
            trace("can_play_Amount is : " + can_play_Amount);
            if (can_play_Amount <= 0)
            {
                trace("Warning: Banner Anim is either longer than allowed time limit or has a play length of zero");
            }

        }

        function calculate_Replay(e:Event):void
        {
            trace("Calculating replay function :::::: ");
            trace("Play/looped amount is: " + play_Count);
            trace("Can play amount times is : " + can_play_Amount);

            if (play_Count < can_play_Amount)
            {
                trace("anim_play_length is:" + anim_play_length);
                replay_tings();
                trace("replaying anim");
            }
            else
            {
                animMC.stop();
                trace("reached replaying times (" + can_play_Amount + ") available within limit (" + allowed_playing_Time + " secs)");
                if (can_play_Amount <= 0)
                { trace("Warning: Banner Anim is either longer than allowed time limit or has a play length of zero"); }

                //do something else. Currently just stops since no time for replay
            }

        }

        function replay_tings():void
        {

            animMC.addEventListener("Banner_end", calculate_Replay);
            animMC.play();
            play_Count = play_Count + 1;
            trace("Play Count/loops: " + play_Count);

        }

    }

}
```

Hope it helps. I've put many traces just to give you feedback. Remove any you feel is unnecessary and of course you can optimize the code if you spot something.

Comment: This will get you started it. It counts 5 seconds (5000 milisecs) and then stops the anim. I will update it in a bit to include the other stuff when I understand more what you meant in your above comment

Comment: This is good, however I don't just want to stop the animation after a given time I need it to stop on a specific frame. That is why I have the startFrame and endFrame functions. The idea being that the animation will stop only where the endFrame function is called.

Comment: Am I going to need to house everything in a MC? I had thought that might be the solution but was trying to avoid having to do that if possible.

Comment: See Edit 2 -- Basically you have better control if its all inside an MC. Everything from fading in/out to checking how many frames played is easier if you are dealing an MC instead of Stage. Also you are going to need to trigger an event at the last frame, by travelling in the MC's timeline instead of the main timeline you don't lose scope of any code on frame 1 of main timeline (if any) etc

Comment: Thanks, was hoping to not have to put everything in an MC as that relys on people actually doing it and I won't have control over the way they set their files up but it doesn't look like there is another way to do it. Thanks for your help, went through your code and updated mine based on it.

Comment: No worries glad to help. The only thing to add is some decluttering on the code... In the final version you don't actually need the **Date** stuff & their related lines of code **(_startTime, _endTime, real_Time, date1/2 & elapsed1/2)**. Those were for sketch/testing purposes. To get feedback that times were being calculated correctly. It still works because **anim_start_time, anim_end_time & anim_play_length** calculations are what's really making it good (you were on the right path in your sample code with using getTimer as those do too). Peace